How to pass a data frame as a parameter in Duckdb
Given this data frame:
df=pd.DataFrame({'var1':['S1','S2'],'var2':['aba','saa',],'var3':['ia','ma'],'var4':[42,21]})

The following query results in a Parser Error:
duckdb.sql('''
         drop table if exists dat;

         create table dat as
         select *
         from %s
         where var1='S1'
        '''%(df)
        )

I'm able to get the correct results if I'm not passing a data frame.

Read the doc

Alternatively, quoting from the DuckDB docs:
import duckdb
import pandas

# Create a Pandas dataframe
my_df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': [42]})

# query the Pandas DataFrame "my_df"
# Note: duckdb.sql connects to the default in-memory database connection
results = duckdb.sql("SELECT * FROM my_df").df()


